# Entity Framework and Linq - Comparing DateTime

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have this code

```
public List<CalendarData> GetCalendarData(DateTime day)
    {
        List<CalendarData> list = new List<CalendarData>();
        using (dataContext = new VTCEntities())
        {

            DateTime test = new DateTime(2010, 10, 20, 17, 45, 0);

            var data = from z in dataContext.ReservationsSet
                       where z.start_time.Value == test
                       select z;

            foreach (var r in data)
```

What I'd like to do is have this

```
var data = from z in dataContext.ReservationsSet
                   where z.start_time.Value == day
                   select z;
```

the problem I have is that z.start_time has the time part also.  The DateTime day doesn't have the time part recorded.  Is there a way to compare the the date part of without getting this error

```
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

when I do this

```
var data = from z in dataContext.ReservationsSet
           where z.start_time.Value.Date == test
           select z;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to compute two values, like this:

```
DateTime day = ...;
DateTime nextDay = day.AddDays(1);

var data = from z in dataContext.ReservationsSet
                   where z.start_time.Value >= day &&
                         z.start_time.Value < nextDay
                   select z;
```

Comment: Jon, Thanks, how flipping simple.  I don't know why I make things harder than they are.  You're the man.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `.Date` in Entity Framework.  The easiest way I know to handle this is to make a minimum + maximum day:

```
DateTime test = new DateTime(2010, 10, 20, 17, 45, 0);
DateTime startDay = test.Date;
DateTime endDay = startDay.AddDays(1);

var data = from z in dataContext.ReservationsSet
                   where z.start_time.Value >= startDay && z.start_time.Value < endDay
                   select z;
```